# Splitting words for .rtf file

Tags: python, ms-office, rtf

I would like make a program in Python which will take a .rtf file or input text and add /- sing in words after a, e, i, o, u so when you load text back in Word, words will split at certain situations.

e.g. When you reduce margins

```
Some random te-
 xt in microso-
 ft office.
```

But when you stretch text it should look normal.
**Some random text in Microsoft Office.**
Any suggestions how to split sentences in letters and then add /- after a, e, i, o, u?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? SO is more of a: Here is my code, Here is my Error, Here is What I've Tried format. This seems like you may be just asking for code to be written for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code writing service. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, particularly [ask], before posting your next question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the task. But if you want to add a hyphen after each vowel you encounter in a string, something like this could work:

s = "Some random text in Microsoft Office"

Vowels = "aeiou"

new_s=""

for char in s:

```
 if char.lower() in Vowels:

      char=char+"-"

      new_s +=char

 else:

      new_s +=char
```

print(new_s)

Comment: Man you are a legend, but is there a way to not add - on vovel if it is last letter in word, also is there a way ti add - after R if it is between consonants. Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use the index() method for strings to verify the position of a character, e.g.,    for char in s:
 if s.index(char)==len(s)-1:
  print(char)

Comment: and a condition for "R" in a similar fashion.